# React Router dom v6 nested routing

Tags: reactjs

I saw a video doing nested routing like this, I tried but its not working, so is it possible to do like this or should i use the Outlet way?

```jsx
export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to='/books'>Books</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                <Route path='/books/*' element={<BookRoutes />} />
                <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}


function BookRoutes() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route index element={<BookList />} />
            <Route path=':id' element={<Book />} />
            <Route path='new' element={<NewBook />} />
        </Routes>
    )
}

..
```

Comment: Check this official guide - https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet